# ASP.NET Core Web Api log events from an external server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a service in ASP.NET Core Web Api that will receive requests from users of a SPA.
Each user is a telephone operator, attached to a branch.
In my application, I use a telephone provider. This provider makes available some DLLs that are referenced in my project.
For each operator who makes a login request in my application, I need
perform a registration with the telephony provider, using the DLLs it makes available for integration.
When registering the operator at the provider, an object of type IInstance is returned with the operator's information.
In this object, I need to register events that will occur for the operator, such as incoming call, the end of a call etc.
All of these events are triggered by the phone provider’s server and my application needs to listen for these events,
and notify the SPA through SignalR.

My question is: how to save the IInstance object returned by the provider, with all registered events,
for each user who logs in my service?

Is it possible to use the session to store these instances?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Dial(string user)
{
    IInstance instance = _integrationService.Login(user);
    // I need my application to listen to these events, even after the request ends.
    instance.LoggedAgent.IncomingSessionEvent += Agent_IncomingSessionEventHandler
    instance.LogoutEvent += Instance_LogoutEventHandler;

    return Ok();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Storing Instance of an object in a session, am not sure about that. I would suggest you rather store the user info in a session and use it to initialize the instance any time you need.

If that's not the case, you can serialize the instance into xml and save it in the session or database. That way you can always de-serialize it to the object instance any time you need it.

I hope it make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Ikenna. But in this case, I will not be able to hear the events sent by the provider's server that are registered in each user's `IInstance` instance. I need to keep these objects listening for events. Note: my api will only have one instance on the server, so I won't have any problems with load balancing, for example.